# Sort-of smarter disguised Spammers?

Tags: discussion, spam

So I just had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333466/2357233) pop up in the review queue. What startled me was that this is only a hair away from being a valid answer (albeit a terrible answer that should be downvoted). It contained an answer to the question as well as an example of the user's problem being duplicated. Obviously the last sentence as well as the username is a dead giveaway as to its spammy origins.

[image: Spam answer image]

Has someone developed a spambot with the ability to [sort-of answer questions](http://xkcd.com/810/), or is this just a spam attempt with a better disguise than most?

<sub>I don't actually think that anyone with half a brain would fail to notice that this is in fact a spam answer. I just thought it was interesting that the effort was put in to actually disguise the intent of the answer.</sub>

Comment: `Has someone developed a spambot with the ability to sort-of answer questions` This is easy to do. Just write "I agree with the answer above" for questions with existing answer, and "I recently run into the same problem, and I solve this by using <spam>" for questions with no answer.

Comment: That could actually lead to some interesting answers. `I solved this problem by increasing my stock portfolio by 1000% in just two months`. Now replace stock portfolio with the result of a slightly more common and NSFW spam marketing campaign.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's people being paid to write spam. But I so *wish* someone could write a spam bot that gave us meaningful and lasting contributions, at least once the links are removed. I won't link to the almost-obligatory XKCD here, since it has been linked to death, but..

Duck into a Net Cafe' (or 'computer shop' as they're commonly called) in most parts of SE Asia and you'll see students hard at work at this type of 'marketing' to make ends meet. They have boilerplate text snippets that they're supposed to use, and customize a bit to look less like spam. It's sad, but I don't blame them, I blame the organizations behind it.

While we're working on some enhancements to the spam system, this is one of the reasons that it will *always* be primarily fed by actions that folks take - because as you've just demonstrated, one can't underestimate the power of the human brain to deduce that something isn't quite right.

Comment: and.... I already did link to that particular XKCD in my question.

Comment: where's the link. I wanna see the link!..

Comment: __... in most parts of SE Asia...__. I initially interpreted it as Stack Exchange Asia before actually realizing what you meant. :P

Comment: @CodeNewbie SEO meaning, South East Optimization, right?

Comment: @CodeNewbie Wouldn't be surprised if such a site would pop out sooner or later ;0

Comment: Some people feel bad because they don't know the mentioned XKCD. :(

Comment: @cubuspl42 those people can click the links in the OP's question, and/or read her first comment :)

Comment: Her? Do I have a feminine style of writing? I'm sure that James is a masculine name. *Tongue in cheek, I'm not actually offended*